# Spring Security: How to make anonymous-only content?

Tags: spring-security, roles

I want to make certain pages in my project accessible only to anonymous users (e.g.: /login, /signup) but for some reason other roles are able to access them too.. (It's killing me because the other way around actually works..)

this is my http config:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="dao-auth"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" 
    disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/usermain.html" access="USER"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/home.html" access="USER"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="USER"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="USER"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"></intercept-url>
    <intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"></intercept-url>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login/bad"
        default-target-url="/home" 
        login-processing-url="/authenticate" 
        username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/"
        logout-url="/logout" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            expired-url="/login" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

In order to be restrict against ROLE_ANONYMOUS I had to activate **use-expressions="true"**
in the http tag and then change all my accesses to their equivalent boolean expression (The equivalent to only anonymous is **access="isAnonymous()"** ).